Дискорд бот с использованием tasks.loop
Есть код на Disnake с использованием tasks.loop(minutes=5). При запуске ошибок нет, все работает корректно, и спустя несколько часов бот продолжает работать без проблем. Однако на следующий день он перестает выполнять заданную функцию (отправка сообщения в канал). После перезагрузки бот снова работает корректно, но ситуация повторяется по кругу. Не знаете, с чем это может быть связано?
